# Auto self extract archive with password...Is it possible?

Tags: compression

Is it possible to make an password protected SFX archive (non GUI) and extract it by giving a password via command line ?

Do any of the archive formats support this ? I couldn't find any.

Preferably, I want either 7z, FreeArc or any other high compression format ?

Hope I made it clear.

Comment: You might look at 7-zip's command-line version(s)—see http://7-zip.org. I believe I was able to do this once upon a time, but it's been a while . . . . p7zip also worked when I last tried it a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [7zip](http://7-zip.org/).

```
7z a -p -sfx archivename
```

Will create a self-extracting compressed archive with archive name as `archivename.exe`
You'll be prompted to enter the password upon compressing & extracting, else you can provide it as part of the command itself

Comment: I know how to create one...I wanna be able to extract it via command line, say in a batch file like:
    sfxname.exe password

something like that, is it possible with any ?

Comment: that works with the archive created using above command

Comment: Thanks, it works, is it possible for FreeArc ?

Comment: @untilTHEend according to their [site](http://www.freearc.org/) it should be possible, but I haven't tried it.